# Intepreting results from rails render times

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, solr

I am trying to understand the following line from my rails log:

`Completed 200 OK in 70ms (Views: 5.0ms | ActiveRecord: 7.3ms | Solr: 56213.2ms)`

from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/687758/understanding-ruby-on-rails-render-times) it seems like the `Completed` Time represents the time for the entire request. In my case however, Solr took signficantly longer than the request as a whole.

I'm wondering if either

1. Solr is blocking and the total request time is actually much closer to 56000 ms
2. Solr is not blocking the request and the request completes before solr?

The latter seems less likely since pages would appear incorrectly if solr didn't complete before the render. Option 1 would mean that the benchmarking times are off.